# Storing user id in a custom addapter class in a list

Tags: mysql

I have the following JSON-String:

```
{"Employee_Reports":[{"UserId":"10"},{"UserId":"12"},{"UserId":"13"},{"UserId":"14"},{"UserId":"15"},{"UserId":"1"},{"UserId":"5"},{"UserId":"11"}{"UserId":""}]}
```

I want to store all the UserId in a string array in a custom adapter class:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(route_response);

JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.optJSONArray("Employee_Reports");
for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    status = new String[jsonArray.length()];

    for(int t=0; t<jsonArray.length(); t++) {
        jObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(t);
        status[t] = jObject.getString("UserId");
```

It's not working as it shows an error.

Comment: Which error does it show?